# Equivalent query in entity framework core

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

I have a table, `Item`, which stores key/value pairs:

```
CREATE TABLE Item (
    ItemKey,
    "Key",
    "Value",
    Created,

    CONSTRAINT CK_Key CHECK ( "Key" IN ( 'Item Id', 'Item Name', 'Location', 'Date' ) )
);
```

Below I use *conditional aggregation* to get all the info (key-values) for a `ItemKey` on to one row. Then I use a `where` clause for the required condition. Below works fine.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            [ItemKey],
            MAX( CASE WHEN [Key] = 'Item id'   THEN "Value" END ) AS id,
            MAX( CASE WHEN [Key] = 'Item name' THEN "Value" END ) AS itemName,
            MAX( CASE WHEN [Key] = 'Location'  THEN "Value" END ) AS location,
            MAX( CASE WHEN [Key] = 'Date'      THEN "Value" END ) AS "date"

        FROM
            Item
        GROUP BY
            "ItemKey"
    ) t
WHERE
    location LIKE 's%';
```

Can anyone let me know equivalent query to use in repository class of entity framework core.

In respository class: This is how I retrieve all items from Item table.

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<Item>> GetItems()
{
    return await itemDbContext.items.ToListAsync();
}
```

But I want to get information in the above mentioned query format. So that all info for `ItemKey` is put on to one row. Thank you.

Comment: That's a PIVOT operation. You don't need to use the same query on the client. You can simply calculate the Max per Key where the Key is one of those values and return the results eg as a dictionary by key.

Comment: ...is that an EAV table **anti-pattern**? Can't you normalize your database to do things _properly_?

Comment: Also, what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: If the database uses the EAV antipattern don't try to use an ORM. They simply aren't built for this. You'll have to convert the EAV into a proper relational form eg with a VIEW before you can map properties to fields. In any case you won't be able to write to the database, with or without the view.

Comment: Using Microsoft SQL Server. It is EAV (not quite sure what you mean by anti pattern). I wont be able to change my database structure. I only have to read from the table. No writing required.

Comment: Above repository class method returns list of items but not in the format I require.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos  I rite now get  list of items as json data from backend (but Just not in the format I want). Do you mean to say I can extract the values I want at frontend instead of changing format at backend? Thank you.

Comment: `(not quite sure what you mean by anti pattern)` it means it's a very bad idea that only causes problems. It means you can't use any tools like ORMs because those were created to work with proper tables. You don't get any flexibility with an EAV, you lose all indexing and checks and as you found out, you can neither query nor write to that table  without extremely complicated code

Comment: There's seldom any good reason for such a schema. SQL Server allows you up to 32000 sparse columns. You can have XML or JSON fields. You can use computed columns to expose parts of those JSON fields as actual columns and index them

Comment: For example, how do you know a value is a date? No, the `Date` key doesn't say that. The field is just a string so *anything* can be stored in there. What's the format of that date? YYY-MM-DD? MM/DD/YYYY? How can you filter by that non-date string? Or sort items by it?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. The intention behind using this schema could be, Changes to schema can be achieved without changing the database schema (more keys can be added maybe). And the number of attributes are more, but many hold null values. Again I am not very sure about the intention behind this schema, just a guess.

Comment: @Sarahrb _"Changes to schema can be achieved without changing the database schema"_ - that is not a desirable goal. Whoeever designed this database originally was simply ignorant of best-practices (or even basic database theory...).